# Почему file() не читает кириллицу?

Tags: php, массивы

Пытаюсь занести данные из текстового файла в `file` в массив и сравнить. Но столкнулся с проблемой, что с кириллицей ничего не работает. Если текст в текстовом файле на английском, то все отлично, а если на русском `in_array` отказывается работать.
Файл обработчик:

```php
$text = $_POST["chat"];
if (in_array($text, file(names.txt))) {
    echo "Совпадение найдено!";
 //какой-то еще код
}
```

Файл `names.txt`:

```html
Заказ 
Оформление
Договор
```

Comment: "файл с кириллицей" это очень широкое понятие. Как минимум текст может быть в cp1251/utf-8/utf-16 или даже в 866 (другие кодировки возможны, но маловероятны).

Также фраза "отказывается работать" также очень обширна. Например, скрипт может падать или просто ничего не выводить. В любом случае, нужен "минимальный код, который воспроизводит проблему"

Comment: покажите ваш код, ошибку и приведите пример файла, с которым не работает

Comment: @rjhdby, добавил. В error_log никаких ошибок нет.

Comment: Попробуйте так `file(names.txt, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)`

Comment: @rjhdby, спасибо, заработало

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция `file()` разбивает файл на строки и помещает их в массив. НО(!!!) символ завершения строки не удаляет. Соответственно ваш файл преобразуется в массив:

```
["Заказ\n",
"Оформление\n",
"Договор\n"]
```

Для того, чтобы избежать этой ситуации, необходимо использовать флаг `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` (ну и `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` тоже полезно добавить)

Соответственно:

```
file(names.txt, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```